# What is daily Message Limit for Live ID in terms of storage and count

Tags: c#, email

i have one windows service. that will send mail for every 10 sec. after sending 300+ mails the below error is coming

Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.3.4 Requested action aborted; Our daily message limit was meant to stop spammers--we're sorry that it's getting in your way. You can wait a day to send your message.

can anyone please help me...

Comment: Read the faq's on how to accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending out that many emails and you are not sending out spam you need your own server, you shouldn't be relying on Live to channel your email.

If you don't want your owns server you are probably a spammer, I have some other suggestions for you...

Comment: @ Cos Callis : please suggests me if any other

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://windowslivehelp.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=5ac2a039-9235-412b-8163-0d38baf7d21d). It is response from Microsoft about your problem.